# Customize addthis share button in iphone?

Tags: iphone, addthis

I m using AddThis ([JavaScriptAddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#.T5aQN-3aadY),[IosAddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.T5aXq-3aadY))

for share button to implement in iphone but I want to customize share button.I want to change the text of the button (Share) as displayed below:

[image]

OR

to display just image as:

[image]

I have just add the addthis.h file and 
use addthis as :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

 [AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:self.view withFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 20, 20) forURL:@"http://www.google.com" withTitle:@"Check this out" description:@"Loren ipsum dolor sit amet , consectetuer adipisci"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

How can I do this..???

Comment: how r u using this in objective-c? I mean lines of code please? Coz in the link u provided, they have given diff custom images eg. for diff image, for image & text, for just text & E-mail only button. So code is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hello guys, I have solved this problem u can see the code I have
>   written here.Not genuine but it is working perfectly.The code is as
>   follows:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

 UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc] init];

      btn=[AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:nil 
withFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 20, 20)    forURL:@"http://www.google.com" 
withTitle:@"Check this out" 
description:@"Loren ipsum dolor sit amet , consectetuer adipisci"];

 [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.view addSubview:btn];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

> **and thanks for the quick reply...!**